# How to measure the maximum memory usage of a container?

Tags: node.js, containers

I am a programming novice, currently undertaking the development of my own online judge system as a personal project.

My goal is to retrieve memory usage data following a user's code submission. Specifically, when a user submits Python code, I aim to run it within a Docker container and obtain the result.

While I am aware that **`docker stats`** can provide memory usage information, I am uncertain about the exact implementation details.

The following code snippet utilizes the **`child_process`** module in JavaScript to execute a Python script within a Docker container and retrieve the result:

```
import { exec } from 'child_process'

const execPy = (filepath) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(`docker exec execPython python /app-python/${filepath}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      error && reject({error, stderr})
      stderr && reject(stderr)
      resolve(stdout) 
    })
    
  })

}

export { execPy }
```

And this is my dockerfile

```
FROM python:latest

WORKDIR /app-python
```

This code is designed to run a Docker container, execute Python code, and provide the output. However, it currently does not capture memory usage data.

I am seeking guidance on how to incorporate memory usage tracking into my system, leveraging Docker's capabilities. Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.